# Create Signal R Callback for change on a modelitem

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am stuck in displaying response message from other clients on my web-application. What have i done so far?

**HomeController**

```
private static IHubProxy _hub;
private static HubConnection _connection;
private string url = @"http://server:port/";
private static Model model = new Model(); 

public ActionResult Login()
{
        _connection = new HubConnection(url);
        _hub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("ServerHub");

        _hub.On<string>("ReturnSendMessage", ShowMessage);
        _hub.On<string>("ReturnSignInMessage", ShowMessage);

        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection collection)
{
        model.NickName = collection.Get("NickName");

        _connection.Start().Wait();
        _hub.Invoke("SignIn", model.NickName, true).Wait();

        return RedirectToAction("Chat", "Home");
}

public ActionResult Chat()
{
        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Chat(FormCollection collection)
{
        model.Message = collection.Get("Message");
        _hub.Invoke("SendMessage", model.NickName, model.Message).Wait(); 

        return View();
}

public ActionResult ChatPartialView()
{
        return PartialView("ChatPartialView");
}
```

**View - ChatPartialView**

```
@model DxComWithMe.Models.Model

<div>
    <h3>Chat history</h3>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
        {
           <strong>@item</strong>
           <br>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Everything is working fine, as long as i refresh the page myself. But i want to implement a mechanism which shall update itself after e.g. Model.Messages is changed. Is there anyway to do that or do i have to rely on this method (javascript ...) for implementing a callback functionality: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You are using the .NET client in a MVC application, not gonna work (Not the way you intend to). You need to use the javascript client library

You call client methods like this on the hub from server

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerHub>()
   .Clients.All.SendMessage(...);
```

edit: Are there two servers involved in this?

Comment: i thought so :/ i just wanted to do it like in my wpf client. and no, there is just one server (windows service) which handles the requests.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't handle Hub actions in your controller but in a dedicated Hub class. Signalr relies on javascripton the client side and you have to handle hub events in your client using javascript functions.

You can for instance use [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) in order to bind your dom elements on a js model which will interact with your hub.

Comment: i see. the javascript will be the way. i just wanted to organize it like in my wpf client, but it seems it is not intended to do so. switching to javascript then.